# Custom Button Android that increases percentage on touch event

Tags: android, touch-event

I need to achieve this UI in Android. When sliding right, it increases the percentage and the blue view increases in both ways, and when sliding left it decreases it, both view and percentage in TextView. Any ideas I can do that? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4BvC.png)

Comment: Do you use Compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [library](https://github.com/MackHartley/RoundedProgressBar) that has almost the same design that you need. If it's not convenient for you can check implementation and create your own custom view. Basically you would need to track touch events in `OnTouchListener` and draw on Canvas with coordinates that you got from OnTouch.